# Сохранение Id с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

У меня есть EF 6.x, несколько сущностей и с полем Id у каждой (типа Guid), которые сконфигурены как

```
Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Я получаю данные при синхронизации с сервером и мне требуется сохранять модели с серверными идентификаторами у себя в базе.
Но, к сожалению, единственный метод,который я нашел - это создания нового контекста, но этот метод мне крайне нежелательный.
Так же нашел варианты, где предлагают поставить `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` и задать дефолтное значение для филда, но оно тоже не подходит, т.к. primary key не может быть null.

P.S. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` тоже не подходит.

Спасибо за любые ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь решать две задачи разными способами одновременно - потому и не получается. С одной стороны вам надо чтобы Id генерировались в базе при создании новой записи (потому и `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`) - с другой, вам надо чтобы вы могли их задавать сами (потому и `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`).

Так вот - Entity Framework так **не умеет**.

---

Вариант с `Identity` исключает вставку своих значений в принципе. EF даже не пытается передавать их в БД (потому и IDENTITY_INSERT не срабатывает).

Поэтому вам нужен вариант с `None`. А чтобы база данных не жаловалась что *"primary key не может быть null"* - не забывайте заполнять это поле! Когда вы делаете первичный ключ с атрибутом `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` - вы сообщаете EF что вы **всегда** будете указывать его значение. Вот и создавайте его через `Guid.NewGuid()`.